# Force removal/invalidation of iOS app from user devices

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Assuming you created an app that users have downloaded that is just awful and you neither want to fix it nor have anyone continue to use it so that it won't tarnish your brand, is there a way to end its life on user's iOS devices?

Curious if there is some store setting to force it to work with earlier versions of iOS and invalidates the current app, or code that would force an update that says the app is no longer available.

Comment: Nope... you can remove your app from the App Store, but you cannot remove it from a user's device.

Comment: DonMag is right. However, you can review stats in AppStoreConnect site to find out uninstalls & may very well find that since it is "just awful", that the problem is largely resolving itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many have confirmed, there is no way to remove an application from someone's device. For these cases though, many companies have servers that the application sends a request to on launch, that returns either a need to update the app, a message, or to tell the user the app has been discontinued and that the app cannot be used anymore, stopping them from using the app from there on.

The last use case might be useful to you, but of course this is a proactive solution, not a reactive one.